# Memory leak issue in the generation of multiple images using node-canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, next.js, memory-leaks

I'm generating numerous images using a canvas, and this process consumes 6GB of RAM while producing 5000 images. Unfortunately, the memory is not being released after the processing completes. Despite conducting multiple reviews of my code and attempting various potential solutions, the problem persists. One of the approaches I've tried is using the 'nullify' method. To write the images, I've employed a canvas stream instead of a buffer, necessitating the reinitialization of the canvas within a loop. However, this approach seems to be causing the memory leak issue. I'm seeking guidance on how to address and resolve this matter.

here is my code

```
let tempDnaContainer = JSON.parse(dnaContainer);

  const saveBuffers = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < tempDnaContainer.length; i++) {
    const newDna = tempDnaContainer[i];
      
        let canvas = createCanvas(format.width, format.height);
      let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = format.smoothing;

      await drawElements(canvas, ctx, newDna.attributes, i);

      let stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
      const filePath = `${buildDir}/images/${i}.png`;
      let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

      saveBuffers.push(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          pipeline(stream, writeStream, (error) => {
            stream = null;
            writeStream = null;
            if (error) {
              console.error("Error saving buffer to file:", error);
              reject(error);
            } else {
              resolve();
            }
          });
        })
      );

      stream = null;
      writeStream = null;
}

 await Promise.all(saveBuffers);
  tempDnaContainer = null;
  imageObjects = {};
```

Here is my drawElements code

```
const drawElements = (canvas, ctx, elements) => {
  elements.forEach((element) => {
    const { layer } = element;
    let img = imageObjects[element.loadedImage];

    // Only create a new image object if it doesn't exist
    if (!img) {
      img = new Image();

      img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, layer.posX, layer.posY, layer.width, layer.height);
        imageObjects[element.loadedImage] = null; // Dereference image from cache
        img.onload = img.onerror = null; // Remove event handlers
        img = null; // Dereference local reference
      };

      img.onerror = (e) => {
        console.error(`${e}: ${element.loadedImage}`);
        imageObjects[`${element.loadedImage}`] = null; // Dereference image from cache
        img.onload = img.onerror = null; // Remove event handlers
        img = null; // Dereference local reference
      };

      SetSource.call(img, `${element.loadedImage}`);
    } else if (img.complete) {
      ctx.drawImage(img, layer.posX, layer.posY, layer.width, layer.height);
      imageObjects[element.loadedImage] = null; // Dereference image from cache
      img = null; // Dereference local reference
    }
  });

  // Dereference elements and ctx after use
  elements = null;
  // ctx = null;
};
```